# Istio ServiceEntry for outside db with mutual tls, cannot connect to db service

Tags: istio

I am using ***istio 1.0.2 version*** with **istio-demo-auth.yaml**, I have a mssql db outside the k8s cluster, I want to connect it form the istio injected services. I try with this [Consuming External TCP Services](https://istio.io/blog/2018/egress-tcp/) blogs, but the services cannot connect to the outside mssql instance. The service entry as below:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: mssql-entry
  namespace: multitenancy
spec:
  hosts:
  - mssql-master
  addresses:
  - $outside-db-ip/32
  ports:
  - number: 2433
    name: db
    protocol: TCP
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  resolution: STATIC
  endpoints:
  - address: $outside-db-ip
    ports:
      tcp: 2433

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-master
  namespace: multitenancy
  labels:
    app: v1
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 2433
      targetPort: 2433
      protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: mssql-master
  namespace: multitenancy
subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: $outside-db-ip
    ports:
    - port: 2433
      protocol: TCP
```

And the services' log presenting " Prelogin error: host mssql-master port 2433 Error reading prelogin response: Connection reset ClientConnectionId:", seems not reached the mssql at all. How to configure outside cluster db for mutual tls services?

Comment: I add a destinationrule for mssql, to disable the tls for the mssql connection.

Comment: Does it help you to solve the issue?

Comment: @mk_sta Yes, after I disabled the tls for mssql destination, I can get the mssql connection in my services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SmileSees mentioned, the issue has been resolved by disabling mutual TLS authentication for the target `mssql` instance. Due to the fact that the database instance located outside the Istio mesh and no `sidecar Envoy` injected for this service, TLS security connection was not established.

You can consider to use [SPIFFE](https://spiffe.io/) framework for securing services across heterogeneous environments.

Referenced links for further research:

1. [Mutual TLS authentication](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#mutual-tls-authentication)
2. [Authorization policy](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authorization-policy)
3. [Istio security vs SPIFFE](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#istio-security-vs-spiffe)